# Unserialize in php

Tags: php, serialization

I have this code:

```
{"38":{"0":"24 ","sort_order":"1"},"39":{"0":"35 ","sort_order":"2"}}
```

I need this unserialize. Seems here it is not proper serialized code, because `unserilize()` does not work.
I can unserialize this online here: https://www.unserialize.me/

I got this what I need `print_r()` result:

```
Array
(
    [38] => Array
        (
            [0] => 24 
            [sort_order] => 1
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [0] => 35 
            [sort_order] => 2
        )

)
```

How to unserialize my code in php?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: if its valid json  u can use json_decode() here

Comment: You are looking for [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)

Comment: This is a json object, not a serialized object. Use `json_decode` instead.

Comment: something like `print_r(json_decode($youtString,true));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That string is not serialized, that would be.

```
a:2:{i:38;a:2:{i:0;s:3:"24 ";s:10:"sort_order";s:1:"1";}i:39;a:2:{i:0;s:3:"35 ";s:10:"sort_order";s:1:"2";}}
```

Your string is JSON, and you need this

```
$variable = json_decode($stringData,true)
```